# How to get data in table using query in bigquery?

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

I am using bigquery API
if i have one table in my dataset and finish to load data , how could i get a list of data using query
for example i would like to retrieve datas using this query:

select * from projetid:datasetid.tableid where size>10

How to use query with bigquery API?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

One can use [BigQuery Web UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui) or [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/)
My understanding is that you are looking to how to start with API.
I recommend to look into [Jobs API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs)
Depends on your case you can choose [Jobs: Insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) or [Jobs: Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query)
This can be good start for you

Comment: Thank you so much, i use bigquery API, and you're reason i'm looking how to start

Comment: Could you give me an example of using this, in the documentation, i don't find any way of the syntaxe, thanks a lot to reply me

Comment: @user3323940 - in what language you need the example?

Comment: ideally, you should pick your prefered client here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries and explore respective documentation

Comment: is it possible to do query insert with job.query ?or only select

Comment: Only select. Have in mind, result is still available in temp table for about 24 hours